# How to print independent chunks of text python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, timer

Situation: Printing a prompt to the screen with a countdown timer

Quick example:

```
Enter selection, default choice will be selected after timer runs out
Timer: 01:05
(1) Selection 1 (Default)
(2) Selection 2
(3) Selection 3

Selection:
```

The Timer has to keep running while the user must be able to key in the selection uninterrupted. Here is the code for the timer. Everything as of now is being printed using `print()`.

```
def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, sec = divmod(t, 60)
        hours, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
```

Problem: This would mean that the prompt and the countdown timer (as of now my timer is blocking [called from a method]) will need to be mutually exclusive

Question: How do I make those two chunks of text independent of each other such that the timer will continue ticking, but the prompt and user input will not be affected by the timer's countdown (using "\r")

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate thread which will update the timer, and a thread which will read the user input.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate a bit, if possible give some sample code or link to some sample code? Cannot seem to find this anywhere else